Register for Scanning notification in WIA
I'm trying to register to all WIA events as defined here.

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using WIA;

[...]

        public ScannerService()
        {
            try
            {
                deviceManager = new DeviceManager();
                foreach (String wiaEvent in wiaEvents)
                {
                    deviceManager.RegisterEvent(wiaEvent, "*");
                }
                deviceManager.OnEvent += OnDeviceEvent;
                Console.WriteLine("Listening for WIA events. Press Enter to exit.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Exception: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }

That works for connect and disconnect, and whenever I scan using the scan button.
However I'd like to get the event when I scan using another software, for example the Windows Scan.
Is it possible ?
